# TextChanged event not firing for text box, when the text is changed from javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box which i m filling of date from the calendar extender and the code is as below:-

```
<label for="input-one" class="float"><strong>Date</strong></label><br />                  
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="inp-text" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="true"
             Width="300px" ontextchanged="txtDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDate2" runat="server" AlternateText="cal2" 
                 ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Images/icon_calendar.jpg" style="margin-top:auto;" 
                 CausesValidation="false" onclick="btnDate2_Click" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calExtender2" runat="server" 
                              Format="dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy" 
                              OnClientDateSelectionChanged="CheckDateEalier" 
                              PopupButtonID="btnDate2" TargetControlID="txtDate" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtDate" ErrorMessage="Select a Date" Font-Bold="True" 
                            Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
```

Javascript code is :-

```
function CheckDateEalier(sender, args) 
{
    sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
}
```

My requirement is that as the date is entered in to the textbox, I want to call this method:

```
public void TimeSpentDisplay()
{
        string date = txtDate.Text.ToString();
        DateTime dateparsed = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy", null);
        DateTime currentDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        if (dateparsed.Date > currentDate.Date)
        {
            divtimeSpent.Visible = true;
        }
        if (dateparsed.Date < currentDate.Date)
        {
            divtimeSpent.Visible = true;
        }
        if (dateparsed.Date == currentDate.Date)
        {
            divtimeSpent.Visible = false;
        }
}
```

Please help me that how i achieve this as i m calling this method inside `txtDate_TextChanged` method but the event is not firing as the text is changed inside the textbox.

Please suggest how I can achieve this or give me an alternate idea to fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fixed it as i the text box is inside an ajax update panel and that's why the event is not firing.I had added a trigger in the update panel for that text box and it worked fine.

Comment: kindly add what you have tried. It will be more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

you have to change the AutoPostBack property of the textbox to true.

Hope this may helps you.

Comment: i did that but still the txtDate_TextChanged event is not firing.You can see in the code also that it is set to true.

Comment: PLEASE CHECK THAT IS YOUR EVENT WORK BY SIMPLY WRITING THE TEXT IN TEXTBOX

Comment: No it is not working, i enable the text box and i changed the textbox text manually but the event not fired.